# Listing players who have various roles in Discord

Tags: javascript, discord

var Players = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleID1','roleID2','roleID3','roleID4','roleID5','roleID6','roleID7').members.map(m=>m.user.tag);

^Right now, this line of code for my discord bot retrieves a list of players that have ALL of the roles with those role IDs. It then dumps this player list into an array named 'Players'

Instead of having it look for players that have ALL of those roles, how can I change this line to instead look for players that have ANY ONE of those roles? Or do I have to actually search for individual roles multiple times and add them to the array for a munch longer, uglier code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can pass only one parameter to the [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)[.get()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) method. Your code will only get the members of the role `roleID1`.

To go around this you can make an array with all the role IDs you want to get and use [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)[.filter()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter):

```js
const RolesArray = ["roleID1", "roleID2", "roleID3", "roleID4", "roleID5", "roleID6", "roleID7"];
const Roles = Guild.roles.cache.filter(role => RolesArray.some(roleValue => roleValue == role.id));
```

`Roles` is now a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) (just like Guild.roles.cache) containing the roles in `RolesArray`.

Now you can map the roles by `members` and then map `members` by `ID`.

```js
const Members = Roles.map(role => role.members.map(member => member.user.tag));

// It will return an array with each member for each role.
// --> [["Role1Member", "Role1Member"], ["Role2Member", "Role2Member]];
```

---

Now, we can create an array of members and add every member in it. But if a member has 2 or more roles, their tag will be duplicated. So we'll make sure to remove it.

```js
const RolesArray = ["roleID1", "roleID2", "roleID3", "roleID4", "roleID5", "roleID6", "roleID7"];

const Roles = Guild.roles.cache.filter(role => RolesArray.some(roleValue => roleValue == role.id));
const Members = [];
// This will be our final result, without duplicates.
let UniqueMembers = [];

// Looping through each role and the members of the role and adding them to the Members array.
Roles.map(role => role.members.map(member => member.user.tag)).forEach(memberArray => {
    memberArray.forEach(member => {
        Members.push(member);
    });
});

// Removing the duplicates.
UniqueMembers = Members.filter(function(item, position) {
    return Members.indexOf(item) == position;
});

// Logging our final result, without duplicates.
console.log(UniqueMembers);
```

Comment: I get an error on the line: const Roles = guild.roles.cache.filter(role => RolesArray.some(roleValue => roleValue == role.id)); ... "ReferenceError: Guild is not defined"

Comment: You need to define the guild. In your case, you can replace `Guild` with `message.guild`.

Comment: What I have currently: https://pastebin.com/XCRuHswH ... I added a push to add a 'Dummy' entry to the UniqueMembers array... but when I actually run this - it always comes out with just the Dummy in it, even if a member had one of the correct roles

Comment: The problem is at your `RolesArray`. You combined `"` and `'`. As I can see it is one big String. Change the `RolesArray` with: `const RolesArray = ['737531569165565982','737533396422754355','737533710798290974','737532883539066971','737533050925350932','737533864544567296','737534067188301854'];`